# what is the meaning of this statement'' dispassion for what has to be heard and what has been heard.''(Gita chapter 2 verse 52)

Tags: bhagavad-gita

Gita chapter 2 verse 52:-

> yadā te moha-kalilaṁ buddhir vyatitariṣhyati
> tadā gantāsi nirvedaṁ śhrotavyasya śhrutasya cha

source :https://bhagavadgita.io/chapter/2/verse/52/

Meaning :When your mind will go beyond the turbidity of delusion, then you will acquire dispassion for what has to be heard and what has been heard.

My confusion is that  Im not getting the meaning of this statement''you will acquire dispassion for what has to be heard and what has been heard''.

Im thinking that its talk about dispassion for Bhagavad gita lecture  or you  have already heard  the Gita lecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that a man who has attained moksha goes beyond the teachings of the scripture. He has directly experienced the Truth and does not depend on scripture for spiritual teachings.

> Scriptures are unnecessary for the man who has attained the insight.
> See Gita II.46; VI.44. He who attains the wisdom of the Supreme passes
> beyond the range of the Vedas and the Upanishads,
> *sabdabrahmativartate*.

**Commentary on Gita 2.52 by S. Radhakrishnan**